# Prevent pgfplot line clipping without extending axis

Tags: pgfplots

By default pgfplots has a nasty habit of cutting peaks off
[image]
Adding `enlarge y limits={abs=0.6pt}` seems to fix this
[image]
But now I have an unsightly stub at the ends of my axis

[image]

I'd rather like to get rid of this, but can't see how.
If someone could point my in the right direction that would be very much appriciated :)

### MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{
    compat=newest,
    no marks,
    axis lines=middle,
    axis on top,
    every axis plot/.append style={very thick},
    enlarge y limits={abs=0.6pt}, % prevent clipping of plot lines
}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[domain=0:pi]
            \addplot+{sin(deg(x))};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

#### Issue with the `clip=false` solution

This was suggested, and does indeed seem to solve this issue, however it creates another. For asymptotic functions (e.g. changing to `1/x` with `ymax=5`) then produce their own set of issues. Given that this is going inside a global setting, I'd rather not have to worry about this.

[image]

#### Issue with shorten inner axis line

When plotting some other functions (e.g. 1/(x+1)), the origin develops a 'gap'.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Does `enlarge y limits={abs=0.6pt, upper}` work?

Comment: It would, however with something exact (line this sine graph) there's still a visual niggle (just at the top). Also, I'd rather (if possible) have this as a "set and forget" type thing, so I won't have to switch for graphs with a negative minimum, or positive maximum.

Comment: Could you add the code of that example to your question? Makes it easier to test.

Comment: Sure :) I'll cut it down a bit for practicality though

Comment: NB: For the visual niggle with the top, by exact I mean the maximum is exactly one of the tick-marks. I.e. for sine max value=1, so there's a little stub beyond that tick mark.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. question updated to show issues with `clip=false`

Comment: I know that is the problem with `clip=false`, hence my "depending on use case".  It's not really related to asymptotic functions though, but that you set the axis limits such that the plotted function have points that lie outside the axis limits.

Comment: Hmm. Perhaps I'm asking for a bit much then. What I was thinking might exist is either a way to slightly expand the clip, or just restrict the axes length.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if this will work for all cases, but possibly the combination

```
    enlargelimits={abs=0.6pt},
    inner axis line style={shorten >=0.6pt, shorten <=0.6pt}
```

will work. The first will extend the axis limits by a bit more than half the line width, which will also extend the axis lines. The second line will shorten the axis lines by the same amount.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{
    compat=newest,
    no marks,
    axis lines=middle,
    axis on top,
    every axis plot/.append style={very thick},
    enlargelimits={abs=0.6pt},
    inner axis line style={shorten >=0.6pt, shorten <=0.6pt}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[domain=0:pi]
            \addplot+{sin(deg(x))};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Seems to work! Same issue as my other question then, but this one seems to be solved!

Comment: @tecosaur Your second question is kind of a duplicate of this, yes.

Comment: I may have been better of combining them, I just wasn't sure if there'd have different enough solutions to be worth separating.

Comment: @tecosaur Well, depends a bit on how you look it. The question of how to set the `line cap` for plot lines is not a duplicate of this. But the line cap wasn't really the problem, the problem was the same as here: that `pgfplots` clips off everything outside the axis limits, and when the axis limits are the same as the data limits, about half the line width is cut off.

Comment: Good answer....with specific details...thererefore...upvote.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. I've discovered an issue: If I change the plotted function to 1/(x+1) now there's a gap at the origin. See updated question

Comment: @tecosaur It's possible that I'm just overthinking this, did you ever try a bigger value for enlargelimits, with no shortening of the axis lines? E.g. just `enlargelimits={abs=3pt,upper}`?