# Round line cap for pgfplot

Tags: pgfplots

I'm not a huge fan of how pgfplots cuts off plot lines by default

[image]

I'd much prefer the look if the `line join=round,line cap=round` TikZ keys could be applied to graphed lines. However adding those keys to `\pgfplotset` doesn't work, and I can't find the correct sub-category to use (e.g. `every plot axis/.append style`).

If someone could give me a hand with this that would be fantastic.

#### MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{
    compat=newest,
    no marks,
    axis lines=middle,
    axis on top,
    every axis plot/.append style={very thick},
    enlarge y limits={abs=0.6pt}, % prevent clipping of plot lines
    every axis plot/.append style={line join=round,line cap=round,clip=false}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[domain=0:pi]
            \addplot+{sin(deg(x))};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Hmhh, when I try `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[axis lines=middle]
 \addplot[domain=-4.5:4.5] {x^3};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round]
\begin{axis}[axis lines=middle]
 \addplot[domain=-4.5:4.5] {x^3};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}` I do see a difference in the line caps. Can you please explain what you mean by "does not work"?

Comment: It should be `every axis plot` I think. I guess for that example you need `clip=false` as well.]

Comment: @Schrödinger's cat I'm trying to do this in the `\pgfplotsset`, @TorbjørnT. tried that, didn't work, MWE added.

Comment: `clip=false` doesn't go inside the `every axis plot`, but outside. Depending on your use case `clip=false` might also be sufficient for your other question by the way.

Comment: Needs to be `every axis/.append style`, not `every axis plot/.append style`.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat For setting line caps etc. for plot lines, doesn't `every axis plot` make more sense?

Comment: clip=false outside does do it! I have got one concern though, which I'll communicate in my other question

Comment: @TorbjørnT. It very well be that I am misinterpreting the question. Nonetheless the key I mention does change the plot and axis line caps.

Comment: `every axis plot/.append style` + `clip=false` works for me!
(just `clip=false` produces it's own issues as seen in https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/510172/prevent-pgfplot-line-clipping-without-extending-axis )