# Expand pgfplots bounding box

Tags: pgfplots

This is fairly simple. I want to expand the bounding box of my pgfplots without using `enlargelimits` or `clip=false`.

#### Why?

See [Prevent pgfplot line clipping without extending axis](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/510172/prevent-pgfplot-line-clipping-without-extending-axis)

#### Why not `enlargelimits`?

Because I'd like it when there's a 'neat' domain for the tick marks to work out 'neatly' too.

[image: the uglyness]

#### MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{
    no marks,axis lines=middle,
    enlargelimits={abs=1pt},
    minor x tick num=1,
    every x tick/.style={color=black, thin},
    every y tick/.style={color=black, thin},
}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[domain=1:2]
            \addplot+{x};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

#### Some clarifications

I like to thicken the line, by default this causes issues with clipping (see the linked question). `enlargelimits` fixes this, but brings it's own issue with the tick marks as mentioned earlier. What I want to see is something like below when it should be a 'clean' (i.e. nice numbers) plot, e.g. `y=x` with `domain=1:3` should produce something more like this

[image: better]

while still expanding the clipping bounding box.

I hope this makes things clearer.

### A longer version (sorry)

To provide a fuller picture of the issue, here's a bigger example.

#### With `enlargelimits` (issues circled)

[image: image3]

#### Without `enlargelimits` (issues circled)

[image]

#### MWE 2

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,calc}

\pgfplotsset{
    compat=newest,
    no marks,
    % -- AXIS
    axis lines=middle,
    axis on top,
    % -- AXIS ARROWS
    inner axis line style={draw=none},
    clip mode=individual,
    execute at end axis={
        \path[tips=proper] let \p1=($(rel axis cs:1,1)-(current axis.origin)$),
        \p2=($(current axis.origin)-(rel axis cs:0,0)$)
        in %\pgfextra{\typeout{\x1,\x2,\y1,\y2}}
        \ifdim\x1>1.5pt
            (current axis.origin) edge[-{Latex[round,length=\ifdim\x1<3mm 1.2mm\else 2mm\fi]}]
            ($({rel axis cs:1,0} |- {current axis.origin})+($(1.36mm,0)-(0,0)$)$)
        \fi
        \ifdim\x2>1.5pt
            (current axis.origin) edge[-{Latex[round,length=\ifdim\x2<3mm 1.2mm\else 2mm\fi]}]
            ($({rel axis cs:0,0} |- {current axis.origin})+($(-1.36mm,0)-(0,0)$)$)
        \fi
        \ifdim\y1>1.5pt
            (current axis.origin) edge[-{Latex[round,length=\ifdim\y1<3mm 1.2mm\else 2mm\fi]}]
            ($({rel axis cs:0,1} -| {current axis.origin})+($(0,1.36mm)-(0,0)$)$)
        \fi
        \ifdim\y2>1.5pt
            (current axis.origin) edge[-{Latex[round,length=\ifdim\y2<3mm 1.2mm\else 2mm\fi]}]
            ($({rel axis cs:0,0} -| {current axis.origin})+($(0,-1.36mm)-(0,0)$)$)
        \fi;
    },
    % % -- TICKS
    minor x tick num=1,
    every x tick/.style={color=black, thin},
    every y tick/.style={color=black, thin},
    tick align=outside,
    %
    every axis plot/.append style={
        very thick,
        line cap=round
    },
    samples=100,
    enlargelimits={abs=1pt}, % prevent clipping of plot lines
    % inner axis line style={shorten >=0.6pt, shorten <=0.6pt},
}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[domain=1:2,small]
            \addplot+{x};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[domain=1:2,small]
            \addplot+{x^2/2-x};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Do my clarifications help?

Comment: Not really. I get your target output with `axis lines=left,` and by dropping `enlargelimits={abs=1pt},`.

Comment: Sorry about that. While that does solve that specific solution, I'm looking for a general approach (i.e. axis still go through (0,0) if the domain is -1:1) which expands the clipping box without causing the issues of `enlargelimits`. Might it be worth emailing the package author to ask if such a thing is possible?

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean. Does the new "A longer version (sorry)" help?

Comment: Thanks! (It is very late here but now this looks like a very good question to me, +1)

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat any ideas?