pgfplots: Make axis invisible for intervals outside of explicitly given tick marks when height, minimum and maximum axis value is defined
I am in the process of making nomograms. This involves creating axes with ticks, but no plotting of data. In some cases only parts of the nomogram axis is useful, and I therefore wish to make the obsolete parts of the axis invisible. When making the nomograms I specify the height of the axis, and the minimum and maximum y-values for the axis. These are determined from calculations and cannot be altered. Then I specify the ticks and tick labels at y-values of interest.
My specific question is for a solution which makes the axis invisible for all values on the axis larger than the defined maximum y tick (150 in the MWE) and for all values less than the defined minimum y tick (5 in the MWE).
The vertical position of the y ticks and labels must not be altered, as this breaks the nomogram.
I know axis line style = {shorten >=u, shorten <=v} can be used to shorten the axis without vertically moving the axis, however this requires specifying distances u and v which I would like to avoid. I am looking for a more elegant solution to the problem.
See also picture below illustrating what I am looking for.
MWE for single y axis:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{semilogyaxis}[
            height=.8\textheight,
            ymin = 1,
            ymax=1000,
            log basis y={2},   
            axis x line=none,
            xmin=0,xmax=2,
            ytick={5,50,150},
            ytick align=outside,
            yticklabels={5,50,150},
            ]
        \end{semilogyaxis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}



You‘ll certainly need to say more about this axis in relation to other things you have in your nomogram(s). Please clarify this in your question (not comment). Thank you

I would take a different approach to achieve this. My go-to approach would be to remove the clip around the axis using clip=false.  This allows you to draw outside the axis. See also, https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/510172/prevent-pgfplot-line-clipping-without-extending-axis

@Jasper Can you elaborate how clip=false would achieve the desirable outcome? I looked at the suggested question, but I fail to understand how this brings me closer to a solution. Please let me know if I am missing something.

I suggest that you continue to specify the height as you are, and use clip=false. Then you can have a nomogram which extends upward past the axis tip, without having to extend the axis itself. Position the tick labels accordingly. Please let me know is this doesn't work. Maybe there are some plain TikZ options too.

@Jasper I couldn't get your proposed solution to work, but I found another solution myself. If you are interested, see my answer to this question.

I found a solution by removing the axis line adding inner axis line style = {draw=none},. Then I used  pgfplots coordinate system and drew a thick line between the tick marks of interest by adding \draw[thick] (axis cs:0,5) -- (axis cs:0,150);. This solution provides no gaps between the axis line and tick marks. I also find it quite elegant.
MWE with solution:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{semilogyaxis}[
            height=.8\textheight,
            ymin = 1,
            ymax=1000,
            log basis y={2},   
            axis x line=none,
            axis y line=center,
            axis y line*= center,
            xmin=0,xmax=2,
            ytick={5,50,150},
            ytick align=outside,
            yticklabels={5,50,150},
            inner axis line style = {draw=none}, % removes axis line but keeps ticks
            ]
            \draw[thick] (axis cs:0,5) -- (axis cs:0,150); % draws new axis line between the ticks of interest.
        \end{semilogyaxis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


May be it was too obvious? Change the y-limits.

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{semilogyaxis}[
            height=.8\textheight,
            ymin = 5,
            ymax=150,
%            ymin = 1,
%            ymax=1000,
            log basis y={2},   
            axis x line=none,
            xmin=0,xmax=2,
            ytick={5,50,150},
            ytick align=outside,
            yticklabels={5,50,150},
            ]
        \end{semilogyaxis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


This does not solve my question. Your proposed solution shifts the plot vertically, which will destroy the nomogram. The ymin and ymax must remain at what I initially set them to be. You can see this by additionally adding this to the TikZ picture:
\begin{semilogyaxis}[
   at={(30ex,0)},
   height=.8\textheight,
   ymin = 5,
   ymax=150,
   log basis y={2},   
   axis x line=none,
   xmin=0,xmax=2,
   ytick={5,50,150},
   ytick align=outside,
   yticklabels={5,50,150},
   ]
  \end{semilogyaxis}

Ok. So your question needs improvement. Please edit it accordingly. Thank you
